# How to Pickle Django Model

Tags: python, django, pickle

I'm currently trying to pickle certain Django models. I created a `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` method for the model, but it looks like `pickle.dumps()` is using the default `__reduce__` instead.

Is there a way to force use of `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` ? If not, what is the best way to overwrite `__reduce__` ?

I am currently using Django 1.6 and Python 2.7.6, if that helps.

In essence, I am using get and set state to remove two fields before pickling in order to save space.

Comment: Why pickle it when you can either store it in a db (if you are trying to persist it) or convert it to json (if you are trying to transmit it to someone else)..?

Comment: Hey there! So that's what I'm trying to avoid. The idea is to store the pickled object in a cache rather than hitting a database. Converting to json is difficult as I've found it hard to get the original object back from the json data, which is needed in my implementation

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to cache your models. That will lead to a number of data consistency problems later on. What is the performance problem you're actually trying to solve with this?

Comment: Caching models is the way I want to go for now and I've put in the checks in need to handle data consistency. In general, the issue is that my database is being hit very often for these models and so I'd like them to be cached and then updated in bulk at a later time. I am avoiding json as the model has certain functionality I want to maintain in other areas of my code base

Comment: What you're describing doesn't make sense. Are you trying to cache the result of a particular query? Because loading a model out of the db based on its primary key will not be significantly faster than pulling the instance out of a pickle file, etc. If you're having performance issues it's probably template generation, or bad query indexing.   If you can describe in more detail what performance problem you're having we can better help you solve it.

Comment: This is almost certainly a case of premature optimization as @polpak has said there is absolutely no need to cache objects like this. Secondly if you use django.core.cache objects are pickled automatically you don't need to do it yourself. Thirdly pickling is such a bad choice because it's not guaranteed to be compatible between different versions of django. Your upgrades are going to kill you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's not really the "answer" to my question, the best solution I found was to implement a `dehydrate()` method on the model, allowing me to alter the model's `__dict__` and store that instead.

On recovery from the cache, it's as simple as using the `**` syntax and you'll have your original model back.

Answer (score 0):

Using pickle getstate/setstate you can have your models automatically pickle just the primary key and use it to load when unpickle.

[https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.**getstate**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__)

Like so:

```
class FooModel(Model):
    field1 = CharField()

    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.pk

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.pk = state
        self.refresh_from_db()
```

This let's you pickle django models and all it stores is the primary key. Then when you unpickle it it does a fetch for the fields using the primary key.